# ¿Cómo mantener una base de datos local sincronizada con un webservice?

Tags: android, webservice, kotlin, android-fragment, room

Llevo unos meses programando en `Android Kotlin` a base de tutoriales de google y otros recursos. Mi objetivo es crear una app para una empresa de autobuses donde se vean las líneas, paradas y tiempos. Para las líneas y paradas he de hacer una llamada a un `webservice soap` y almacenarlo en la base de datos de la app con `Room` siempre que sea necesario (antes de descargar se hará comprobación de si es necesario, es decir, si los datos en el webservice han cambiado). Tengo la app bastante avanzada, pero he visto que la lógica no es correcta. En este caso, inicializaba la base de datos en una clase `Application`, punto desde el cual, además, se llamaba al `webservice`, se inicializa el `Repositorio` y otras cosas como se puede ver en el código a continuación.

```
class BusApplication: Application(),BusApplicationInterface {

    val database by lazy { BusDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
    val repository by lazy { StopRepository(database.stopDao(),this) }
    val favorites by lazy {PrefsFavorites(this)}
    val queue: RequestQueue by lazy { Volley.newRequestQueue(this)}
    val soapClient by lazy {SoapClient(queue)}
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        scope.launch {          

            repository.initialize(soapClient)
        }
    }

    override fun getDatabaseInstance(): BusDatabase {
        return database
    }

    override fun getRepositoryInstance(): StopRepository {
        return repository
    }

}

interface BusApplicationInterface{
    fun getDatabaseInstance():BusDatabase
    fun getRepositoryInstance():StopRepository
}
```

El fallo de esta lógica es que solo se actualiza la base de datos si el usuario cierra y abre la aplicación, nunca mientras esté en segundo plano y vuelva a primer plano. Para que esto funcione cada vez que la aplicación vuelve a primer plano, creo que debería hacer la inicialización en la única `Activity` que tiene mi app (`MainActivity`), pero tampoco lo tengo claro. Dado que uso una estructura de `1 Application + X Fragments` ¿cómo podría incluir aquí una pantalla de carga antes de mostrar el menú principal?.

En general, estoy un poco perdido en como debe ser la estructura de la aplicación. La idea es: Aplicación en primer plano -> comprueba si hay que llamar al webservice y alimentar base de datos -> mostrar pantalla de carga si se actualiza -> mostrar menú principal. ¿Me podríais dar alguna pista de por donde continuar?. Gracias.

**Actualización**

*MainActivity*

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_BUS)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController : NavController = navHostFragment.navController
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)      

        val repository = BusApplication.getBusApplication()!!.repository
        val soapClient = BusApplication.getBusApplication()!!.soapClient

        scope.launch {           

            repository.initialize(soapClient)
        }


    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val repository = BusApplication.getBusApplication()!!.repository
        val soapClient = BusApplication.getBusApplication()!!.soapClient
        scope.launch {           

            repository.initialize(soapClient)
        }
    }
}
```

*StopRepository*

```
class StopRepository(private val stopDao: StopDao, private val context: Context) {

    // Room executes all queries on a separate thread.
    val allStops : Flow<List<Stop>> = stopDao.loadStops()

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(stop: Stop) {
        stopDao.save(stop)
    }

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insertAllStops(stops: List<Stop>) {
        if(!stops.isNullOrEmpty()){
            stopDao.insertAll(stops)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteAll() {
        Log.i("deleteAll", "Borrado BBDD")
        stopDao.deleteAll()
    }

    fun getStop(stopCode: String) = stopDao.loadStop(stopCode)

    fun count() = stopDao.count()
    
    fun initialize(soapClient: SoapClient) = runBlocking{
        /*Si hay conexión, borramos bbdd y la renovamos*/
        if (NetworkUtils().checkConnection(context)) {            
            stopDao.deleteAll()
            initializeStops(soapClient)           
        }

        else
        {
            DialogBox("No se detecta conexión o esta es muy débil. " +
                    "La aplicación funcionará con los datos almacenados si los hay.",
                    "Aceptar",
                    true).showDialog(context)
        }
    }

    suspend fun initializeStops(soapClient: SoapClient){
        val response =""
        Log.i("initializeStops", "running")
        var stops = mutableListOf<Stop>()
        soapClient.getSoapResponse(SOAP_STOPS_ENVELOPE, object : VolleyStringResponse {
            override fun onSuccess(response: String?) = runBlocking{

                val doc = Jsoup.parse(response, "", Parser.xmlParser())

                doc.select("StopsDTO").forEachIndexed { index, element ->
                    val stop = Stop(
                            0,
                            element.select("stopCode").text(),
                            element.select("stopDescr").text(),
                            element.select("logicStopCode").text(),
                            element.select("logicStopDescr").text(),
                            element.select("latitude").text(),
                            element.select("longitude").text()
                    )
                    stops.add(stop)
                }
                if (stops.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Log.w("initializeStops", "Stops no está vacío")
                } else {
                    Log.w("initializeStops", "Stops ESTA VACIO")
                }
                Log.w("stops size", "${stops.size}")
                //insercion directa en la bbdd
                insertAllStops(stops)                

            }

            override fun onError(error: VolleyError?) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w("initializeStops", "${error.message} - ${error.stackTrace} - ${error.networkResponse}")                    
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Lee sobre el patrón MVVM y Clean Architecture, así como sobre *Inyección de dependencias* (Hilt preferiblemente). Para traer datos desde el WebService puede que necesites Retrofit y RXJava para observar las actualizaciones... Son las herramientas que necesitas para armar una aplicación con una arquitectura limpia y fácil de mantener. [Aquí tienes un tutorial](https://devexperto.com/clean-architecture-android/) para empezar. Te advierto de que es un mundo nuevo en el que hay muchas cosas por aprender, pero te asegurdo de que vale la pena una vez tienes todo ensamblado.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @A.Cedano, lo cierto es que ya miré e implementé el patrón MVVM (principalmente en los Fragments). He seguido los ejemplos de google, por lo que tengo una database, un repo para las paradas y otro para las favoritas (en adelante otro más para las líneas), así como las clases `ViewModel` correspondientes. No conocía clean architecture. Para las peticiones uso `Volley` y le agrego en el header el `xml soap` necesario para cada petición, eso funciona bastante bien, y también uso `LiveData`. Sin embargo, no consigo resolver el problema de la carga inicial.

Comment: Lee [ask]. Tu post incluye múltiples preguntas y además algunas son basadas en opiniones.

Comment: Con *Inyección de dependencias* (sobre todo con `Hilt`, pues `Dagger` es un poco más complicado) puedes inyectar el `ViewModel` en la vista (`Fragment` o `Activity`  según el caso) con una facilidad pasmosa. Sólo anotarías el Fragment o Activity con `@AndroidEntryPoint`   y para conectar el `ViewModel` con el Repository usas la anotación `@ViewModelInject` en el VM. Volley es una opción para el WS, pero no sé hasta qué punto te permite observar los datos ¿? con Retrofit/RXJava puedes hacerlo sin complicaciones usando `Observable`.

Comment: Gracias @SinneroftheSystem, he cambiado un poco los últimos párrafos para centrar más la pregunta en la pantalla de carga.

Comment: @A.Cedano por el momento la inyección la hago en el constructor de las clases que necesito, pero me miraré más a fondo Hilt para ver las ventajas que puede tener. Aún así sigo dándole vueltas a como mostrar una pantalla de carga hasta que se hayan descargado satisfactoriamente los datos del webservice al inicio/resume de la aplicación. Con Volley en principio es posible observar los datos para ver cuándo cambian.

Comment: He agregado el código de ```MainActivity``` y ```StopRepository``` por si sirviera de algo.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias opciones para resolver esto, todo depende de la cantidad de datos que quieras actualizar y de la frecuencia con la que estos cambien. Pero muy probablemente sincronizar tu base de datos sólo cuando el usuario inicia la app, no es la mejor opción.

Si quieres actualizar mucha información que cambia poco, lo mejor sería hacer algo como un cron job que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo. Si lo implementas usando [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) se ejecutará incluso si la app está cerrada. Si en cambio quieres que sólo actualice cuando esté en primer plano, puedes hacerlo con [corrutinas](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices).

Si la información cambia frecuentemente, una de las mejores opciones es comprobar si está actualizada en el momento que se consulta. Y si no lo está, descargas sólo lo que fue consultado. De esta forma te aseguras de servir siempre información actualizada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La librería [Paging 3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) incluye un componente para este propósito llamado [RemoteMediator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#implement-remotemediator). Usando esta librería es muy fácil implementar ese patrón, usa la base de datos siempre que sea posible y descarga del webservice sólo lo que necesita cuando lo necesita.

[image: remote mediator]

En cualquier caso deberías modificar tu clase `BusApplication`. Veo que la estás usando para crear singletons de tus dependencias, lo cual no está mal pero tampoco es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Nada de eso sería necesario si usaras una librería de inyección de dependencias como [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android).

Y sobre mostrarle una pantalla de carga al usuario, generalmente es mala idea. Lo que se suele hacer es mostrar un [indicador de progreso](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators) pero sin interrumpir
el flujo del usuario. Si esperas que la duración de la descarga sea larga, definitivamente deberías hacerla antes de que se abra la app.

Comment: Bueno, tras esta respuesta me puse manos a la obra con Hilt y lo implementé sin mayores problemas una vez entendí como funciona. Me ha resultado cómodo y útil así que muchas gracias a todos por la sugerencia. Para la carga desde el webservice, esta solo se hará si los datos han cambiado respecto a los almacenados en la bbdd del dispositivo. Para todo eso he creado una Activity auxiliar que hace las veces de pantalla de entrada a la app y lanza la Activity correcta cuando la carga ha finalizado o hay algún error. La cantidad de datos no es grande, así que funciona bastante bien.